# PHPMailer - how to check if address(es) added

Tags: php, phpmailer

You add addresses via `$mailer->addAddress($address['mail'], $address['name']);`. But how do you check if there are any address(es) added to the PHPMailer instance?

Pseudo code:

```
if (count($mailer->Addresses) > 0) {
    $mailer->send();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You can use **getAllRecipientAddresses()** function 
>  of
> PHPMailer class
> to get all the email addresses.

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php#L4988

It allows for public read access to `all_recipients` property.

Comment: Link is currently broken